# Adding files to a PhoneGap App created in CLI

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

If I create an application through node.js, how can I add html and js files to it? Specifically, I created an App in Dreamweaver, but I cannot find the config.xml file. So I want to create a PhoneGap App and add the appropriate files externally and edit the config.xml from there. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the phonegap documentation.
[Phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

Install phonegap, create the app at your project location and build the app. Your `config.xml` file will be generated by the build. Then you can edit it the way you want.

Comment: So I already created a phonegap app and transferred over the js, css, and html file. It reads the files, but when I tried to upload the .zip to PhoneGap the formatting was a mess. I'm wondering if I have to build it locally? I've been reading the documentation but there are not enough examples for me to grasp the process :/

Comment: I was reading and it says I need to update the index.js and the index.css..etc...in order to reference them correctly. Any idea of how to do that?